# equivalent to the idiom 'Even our intestines fight and fall out inside'

Tags: idiom-requests

In arabic, it comes from the noises sometimes heard from our stomachs, and also from peristalses movement that takes place, and the intestine end up touching each other by contracting, squishing and what have you. What it means is that even the very closest of people such as family members, lovers, friends etc will argue and fall out BUT eventually reconcile and things will run smoothly again.'

That thought is taken from the fact, that it is your OWN intestine/your OWN body. It's your own self.

It's said to cheer one up, telling him things will be alright. It's a little humorous.

Comment: Something between "blood is thicker than water" and "water under the bridge"  - except not really. I can't think of anything but there really should be.

Comment: @Avon: Blood is thicker than water under the bridge?!

Comment: I think the phrase itself should be adopted but perhaps with a less literal translation. How about "our own guts squabble inside us"?

Comment: @TusharRaj That has been thought before: https://www.google.com/search?q="Blood+is+thicker+than+water+under+the+bridge" Sadly, I don't think it fits the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your idiom, it seems to me.
1) That even the closest people eventually fight and
2) That because they are close, they eventually work things out

While there are idiomatic expressions in English that might mean one or the other, I can't think of any that simultaneously mean both.

For (2), as has already been suggested, "blood is thicker than water", meaning family ties will overcome any extra-familial disturbances or loyalties.  Another one would be "family is forever" which has different shades of meaning but one being that eventually you have to work out problems with these people because you are stuck with them.  A similar one would be "you can't pick your family" or "you can pick your friends, but you can't pick your family," meaning you must find some way to get along with these people, because you have no other choice.

For (1), there is a subtle difference between EVEN people who are very close eventually fight (let's call this 1a) and BECAUSE people are very close they eventually fight (1b).  I can't think of a good expression for (1a), but there are plenty for (1b): "familiarity breeds contempt", "no one is a prophet in their own land", and "too much kin and less than kind".

Answer (score 0):

You know I couldn't stay mad at you, we're joined at the hip.

Comment: I think this is an excellent suggestion. Your answer would be much more complete (I'd certainly +1) if you could add some extra information, especially to include a citation or reference.

Comment: @Silverfish I figure the important part is knowing what the expression is, then anyone can use a search engine to get more info.

Comment: That is true, but the best content here usually comes with fuller explanation or annotation. It is nice if answers are standalone, so people do not need to search for extra information :)

Comment: @vladkornea That's not how StackExchange works. Answers are supposed to give full and self-contained information by themselves and should require no extra steps of information searching. Here on ELU, that often means linking to Wikipedia pages on technical terms, quoting dictionary (or other source) definitions of words and phrases, etc. Simply giving a suggestion with no explanation or clarification is basically almost always enough to consider an answer inadequate, even if the suggestion itself is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

There is an idiomatic phrase in English, *kiss and make up*. [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kiss+and+make+up) lists several references, such as

> forgive someone and be friends again. *They were very angry, but in the end they kissed and made up. I'm sorry. Let's kiss and make up.*

(citing to *McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs*)

For family members or close friends, the kissing may be literal, but it is often used for reconciliation between less intimate pairs who are unlikely to pucker up, such as formerly sparring politicians.

As in your example, it could be used prospectively -

> I know they're fighting, but don't worry. They'll kiss and make up.

Answer (score 0):

In German there is a useful idiom 'Was sich liebt das neckt sich' (Goethe), meaning teasing/squabbling is a sign of affection.